# How can I make my SVG show up in the <i> tag with no content?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to make my svg show up as a background image in my `<i>` tag. I'm using the `<i>` tag for the sake of uniformity with my other code.

If I do not include any content inside the i tag, the svg background-image fails to show up at all. I have tried setting height and width of the `<i>` tag and that has not worked. I understand you could easily do this with a div but I am trying to make it work the same with this.

HTML

```
<div class="card-panel">
    <i class="icon-advanced"></i>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.icon-advanced {
    background: url('icon/icon-advanced.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

Comment: `<i>` an `inline` element. It does not obey height and width declarations. You'll need to set it to be of type `block`. Try adding `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` to the `<i>` tag and you should be able to not only set a height and width, but also see your background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `display: inline-block;` before setting the height and width

```
.icon-advanced {
    background: url('icon/icon-advanced.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; /* stretch the background to cover the whole element */

    /* 
       still inline, but has block features
       meaning height and width can be set
    */
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}
```